# How to make divs with the same class linked to different URLs in Wordpress via CSS only?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to make the entire testimonial tile clickable in WordPress theme. The theme is Orfeo, the site is storytwirl.com

The testimonial tiles have two divs - the outside div class *card card-testimonial card-plain* that is not linked to anything, and the inside div class *card-avatar* that is linked to the URL.

Linking in the _card-avatar is supported by the theme. But I want the entire div class *card card-testimonial card-plain* to be linked to the same URLs as their inside div class *card-avatar*. There are total three testimonial tiles, and I want for them to link to three different URLs.

I did not find the way to access the HTML via Wordpress and just move links to *card card-testimonial card-plain* divs. I also have not seen anything about this class in php files.

The only difference between the three tiles is the *a href* and *title* in the div class *card-avatar*.

I used "Additional CSS" in Wordpress Customizer to add CSS that makes the divs with class *card card-testimonial card-plain* look like clickable, but I was not able to actually add links into those divs. And I have no idea how to add three different links to each testimonial card using just CSS. Can you help?

Is it possible to take this CSS code, and add a link to each of the three *card card-testimonial card-plain*  divs, different URL to each tile?

```css
/* CSS that makes tiles look clickable but does not add actual links */
div.card.card-testimonial {
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .9;
}

a.divLink {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Makes sure the link doesn't get underlined */
  z-index: 10;
  /* raises anchor tag above everything else in div */
  background-color: white;
  /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
  opacity: 0;
  /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
}
```

Here is HTML:

```
<div class="card card-testimonial card-plain">
<div class="card-avatar">
<a href="http://storytwirl.com/topic/animation-ideas/"><img class="img" src="http://storytwirl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/legal-alien-round-icon-190x190.png" alt="Animation Ideas" title="Animation Ideas"></a>
</div>
<div class="content">
<h4 class="card-title">Animation Ideas</h4>
<h6 class="category text-muted">Stories for Films, Series, Games &amp; More</h6>
<p class="card-description">I have plenty of ideas for animated films, TV series, web series, games, and live action. Variety of styles, variety of audiences, and variety of genres. I would love to develop these ideas with you or jump onto your idea to help to develop it into full production.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you **Andrei Gheorghiu** for answering this question! =)

Comment: Your shouldn't assume anyone is familiar with some WP theme's markup. To put it into perspective: the developer who wrote it won't remember it in 6 months after coding it, especially if he's a busy one. Do provide the actual markup, if you need help.

Comment: I've added a snippet to your answer. Please edit it and place the relevant HTML markup (copy/paste from page's source a card-testimonial) **in the HTML panel**.

Comment: Andrei Gheorghiu - not sure what you mean. If you are talking about actual html code - I tried to add it to my question, by it kept giving me an error that "code dose not look like code" (but for some reason it worked for CSS). And now that I try to post HTML into this comment, it says the post is too long. I am definitely not "assuming" anything - just asking for help in the way I can. The only thing I could do to show the code is to paste it into Google drive - share link here, if it helps. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sZEQkDhNpagkb3QZCanaEYX7cGh_oKhR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do not have "edit" button near my question, so can't add code there - HTML for the card is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10fLNRJvsv_u5CMWaeGXu0of-IeURdkBr/view?usp=sharing  - *Andrei Gheorghiu*  - sorry for inconvenience - Stackoverflow formatting is not working for me yet o_O

Comment: You have an "edit" link under your question. And after you press it, you have an "edit the above snippet" link under it. Nevermind, I found out what I needed. Let me know if what I answered fixes your problem. If not, I need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```js
div.card.card-testimonial {
  position: relative;
}
div.card.card-testimonial a:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
}
```

It creates a `before` pseudo-element on your `<a>` and makes it fill up the nearest parent with `position:relative` (which is the card). It's also rendered above everything else in the card, if nothing inside the card has a set `z-index`.

It practically acts as a catch-all clicks for your card, giving them to its parent, the `<a>`.

**Note:** this technique breaks if any element child of card and ancestor of `<a>` has `position:relative` and it also creates pseudo-elements for **every** link in the card. The card will point to the last link in its DOM in this case, as it will be placed last.

Comment: @ValerieK, consider marking my answer as correct in that case.

Comment: I just did. Hope I did it correctly! (I turned the check mark next to your answer from grey to green). Thanks again!